# @Query can't resolve my database

Tags: java, mysql, database, intellij-idea

So ask users from "customuser" database by @Query annotation. Database is configured and connected to project succesfuly.  But iDEA underline my db name. Here is a code of my class:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomUser, Long> {
@Query("SELECT c FROM customuser c where c.login = :login")
CustomUser findByLogin(@Param("login") String login);

@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(c) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM      customuser c WHERE c.login = :login")
boolean existsByLogin(@Param("login") String login);
```

}

Here is a git with all project: https://github.com/lars1son/MyChat1.2
Can somebody give a hint?) Why is it underline and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. I 've solved:). Underlining is not an error in that case. It compile and ignore underline word.